# How to Use Special Characters in Regex Constructor of Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

In this code i am trying to count the number of times a character is in the array using special character in regex object and get the number that is repeating odd number of times and i want to seperate positive and negative numbers using caret character. But it's not working.

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  //happy coding!

  return A.find( num => A.join(" ").match(RegExp(^num, "g")).length % 2 != 0));
}
console.log(
  findOdd([20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5])
);
```

`output == 5` because here 5 is odd number of times

Comment: `^num` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is:

I concatenated the array using the `join(" ")` as you did and I added a space at the beginning, and I add also a space at the beginning of the regexp, so when you search for "1", you are actually searching for " 1", and for "-1" its " -1", this way they cant get confused, and finally I used the modulo operator `.length % 2 !== 0`  to check if the length is odd or even.

This is a one way to do it.

Check the code, it might help you;

```js
function findOdd (A) {
  //happy coding!
  return A.find((num, i, arr) => ((" " + arr.join(" ")).match(new RegExp(( " " + num ) , "g")).length % 2 !== 0 ));
  
}

console.log(findOdd([20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]))
```

Comment: I think the answer is good but i want to know if i can use special characters in regex constructor.